# Are members inherited from a Superclass's superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose there are three classes: Grandfather, Father, and Son

Assume the following conditions:

- Father extends Grandfather
- Son extends Father

Does Son inherit all members in Grandfather or just the members in Father?

Comment: Normaly, each guy keeps his own member and takes it with him when he dies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Son` will inherit members from `Father`, but since `Father`'s members include those it inherited from `Grandfather`, `Son` will also have them.

> Unless redeclared in the derived class, members of a base class are also considered to be members of the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Its obvious that Son inherit all members in Grandfather too.

Answer (score 0):

A child will inherit all of the parents members and functions. This is also recursive.

The only thing you have to worry about it is its accessibility. The parent might make some functions or members private and so it will be out of the reach of the child. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers).